# 'Recommended' presets not showing on Lightroom Classic (Desktop)

Tags: lightroom, windows

I have installed Lightroom on my Android phone and once I have uploaded a photo, it gives me the option of 'Recommended' presets which I believe uses AI to determine the best filters for that photo.

However, I cannot seem to find an equivalent feature for the desktop program. Is there a way I can activate this or find it within the Lightroom Classic desktop program (on Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such setting in Lightroom Classic. Maybe the reason is you have much larger screen, more convenient input devices (mouse, touchpad, keyboard) and you can browse and preview much faster big amount of presets.